# How to get the value of key from the body of Json response using Postman Test?

Tags: postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Hi Team I have response Json whose body is as below

```
{
"host": "telemarket-backend.val.io",
"ssl-client-verify": "NONE",
"x-request-id": "916633224df75cb3cd728631879612181761",
}
```

when I am writing test in Postman for the above body as described

```
const responseJson=pm.response.json();
pm.test("Validate the SSL ",function(){
pm.expect(responseJson.ssl-client-verify).to.eql("None");
});
```

Above one is not working as expected while the below one is working as expected

```
pm.test("Validate the host  ",function(){
pm.expect(responseJson.host).to.eql("telemarket-backend.val.io");
});
```

can you tell me the reason why is it not working and the fix resolution which can work on postman

Comment: Even if `responseJson.ssl-client-verify` were a legal expression, does None equal NONE?

Comment: Correct solution that I have found out is pm.expect(responseJson[ssl-client-verify]).to.eql("NONE");

Answer (score -1):

Correct solution that I have found out is pm.expect(responseJson[ssl-client-verify]).to.eql("NONE");

Comment: The thing is, this was all present in the comment that I gave you. It seems you didn't even read it? Moreover, you're not _explaining_ anything; you're just throwing the "right" answer at us, without explanation. That's not useful.